# Configuring php-cs-fixer and PATH variable

Tags: php, atom-editor

A while ago, I successfully configured Atom to beautify my PHP using php-cs-fixer, but now I need to go through the same process on another Mac and can't remember exactly how I did it.

As a front-end dev, I'm not a PHP expert, but I understand that the Atom plugin is merely the middleman facilitating the actual fixing using php-cs-fixer, which, by default, it doesn't have access to. Once I installed the fixer, I had to add its location to my `PATH` variable. The confusing part is that I don't have the fixer installed via Atom (checked ~/.atom/packages) nor Homebrew (confirmed with `brew list`), however, the file is present in /usr/local/bin. If I move it, Atom returns the original error, so it's definitely using this file:

```
See https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer for program installation instructions.
Your program is properly installed if running 'which php-cs-fixer' in your Terminal returns an absolute path to the executable. If this does not work then you have not installed the program correctly and so Atom Beautify will not find the program. Atom Beautify requires that the program be found in your PATH environment variable. 
Note that this is not an Atom Beautify issue if beautification does not work and the above command also does not work: this is expected behaviour, since you have not properly installed your program. Please properly setup the program and search through existing Atom Beautify issues before creating a new issue. See https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/search?q=php-cs-fixer&type=Issues for related Issues and https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/tree/master/docs for documentation. If you are still unable to resolve this issue on your own then please create a new issue and ask for help.
Hide Stack Trace
Error: Could not find 'php-cs-fixer'. The program may not be installed.
    at PHPCSFixer.module.exports.Beautifier.commandNotFoundError (/Users/ourcore/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/beautifier.coffee:204:14)
    at /Users/ourcore/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/beautifier.coffee:304:22
    at tryCatcher (/Users/ourcore/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/ourcore/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/ourcore/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/ourcore/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:612:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/ourcore/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:687:18)
    at Async._drainQueue (/Users/ourcore/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/Users/ourcore/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
    at Async.drainQueues (/Users/ourcore/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

`which php-cs-fixer` returns `/usr/local/bin/php-cs-fixer` and my `PATH` variable currently contains `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/ourcore/.atom/packages/php-cs-fixer`.

I guess my questions are, how is the fixer working if the `PATH` variable seems to be pointing to it in a different location, and how did it end up where it is? Does the location in my `PATH` matter at all, or does the Atom plugin know to look in /usr/local/bin? I just want to fully understand the entire process before repeating it.

EDIT: On further testing, I removed the Atom directory from my `PATH` and it didn't affect the plugin, so then I copied the file into the same directory onto the second Mac and it ran without issue, without needing to edit the `PATH`. Does the fixer file someone inform the OS?

Comment: Did you specify `executablePath` in your [settings](https://github.com/pfefferle/atom-php-cs-fixer#settings)? It *should* work without it, but might be worth a try.

Comment: I was going to, and then I noticed it was blank, which makes me wonder how it knows to look in /usr/local/bin.

Comment: The setting is meant to override the default version, so when left blank it uses the one found in your `PATH` ([see source](https://github.com/pfefferle/atom-php-cs-fixer/blob/v2.5.9/lib/php-cs-fixer.coffee#L17))

Answer (score 0):

Well first test "which php-cs-fixer" or "where php-cs-fixer" (depending on what os you're running) and if nothing is returned in the terminal then there actually is something wrong on the installation and the best thing to do is to manually install it.

Head to https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer and download it from there and follow the installation steps, after that it should all be good

Comment: This answer would benefit from incorporating the information from the link. If the link dies, that info is lot *unless* you include it in the answer.

Comment: @Frank Improve your answer because links may expired.

Comment: Calm down guys, that is a github link. If the link dies, it means cs fixer is no longer there!